# Make flexbox children wrap around a child that is multiple rows tall

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am iterating over a list of items(red boxes). I have another element not part of this list that I want to insert into the items' grid in the top right(tall blue box). I am using flexbox and order to position it accordingly. But I want the 2nd row of red items to be 3 items wide and wrap inline with the blue aside. Screenshot of my ideal outcome below. Code at the bottom of my failed attempt.

[image]

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 120px;
}

.flex>div {
  background: red;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  margin: 2px;
  order: 3;
}

.flex>div:nth-child(-n+3) {
  order: 1;
}

aside {
  height: 55px;
  width: 25px;
  margin: 2px;
  background: blue;
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <aside></aside>
</div>
```

Worth noting that I know I can do this with floats but for other reasons unrelated to this problem I'm kind of stuck with flexbox. Open to any & all suggestions though.

Comment: CSS3 Grid layout would do wonders here

Comment: May I ask why to accept an answer that is not dynamic. I mean, as soon as you change the value in e.g. `max-width: 120px`, it breaks, where in mine, it scales.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 120px;
}

.flex>div {
  background: red;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  margin: 2px;
  order: 3;
}

.flex>div:nth-child(-n+3) {
  order: 1;
}

aside {
  height: 55px;
  width: 25px;
  margin: 2px;
  background: blue;
  order: 2;
  margin-bottom: -57px;  /* added */
}

.flex>div:nth-child(6) { /* added */
  margin-right: 27px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <aside></aside>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the solution that best fit my use case. The ideal way is to use css grid. But as that isn't as well supported as flexbox currently I opted for this fully flexbox solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the problem you're facing with flexbox, and several potential solutions:

- [Is it possible for flex items to align tightly to the items above them?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34480760/3597276)
- [Make a div span two rows in a grid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42946454/3597276)

Here's a calculator keypad layout using flexbox:

- [Calculator keypad layout with flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39079773/3597276)

Here's the cleanest and most efficient CSS solution, which uses Grid:

```css
.flex {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 25px;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 120px;
}

aside {
  grid-column: 4;
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
  background: blue;
}

.flex > div {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <aside></aside>
</div>
```

[**jsfiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/aLa1gmwu/)

[**css grid browser support**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46060829/3597276)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version of another answer of mine, which might also qualify as a duplicate, though since it has a simpler CSS, I decided to post it as an answer.

It uses the `order` property and absolute position, to enable the required layout.

Read more here: [Flexbox or Column CSS for positioning elements like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48444823/flexbox-or-column-css-for-positioning-elements-like-this/48446700#48446700)

Stack snippet

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container .right_corner > div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(200% + 10px);
  background: blue;
}

.container::before,
.container > div {
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.container > div:not(:first-child) {
  background: red;
}

.container .right_corner {
  position: relative;
  order: 1;
}

.container::before {
  content: '';
  order: 3;
}

@media (max-width: 600px){
  .container > div:nth-child(n+5) {
    order: 2;
  }
  .container > div:nth-child(n+8) {
    order: 4;
  }
  .container::before,
  .container > div {
    width: calc((100% / 4) - 10px);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 800px){
  .container > div:nth-child(n+6) {
    order: 2;
  }
  .container > div:nth-child(n+10) {
    order: 4;
  }
  .container::before,
  .container > div {
    width: calc((100% / 5) - 10px);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .container > div:nth-child(n+7) {
    order: 2;
  }
  .container > div:nth-child(n+12) {
    order: 4;
  }
  .container::before,
  .container > div {
    width: calc((100% / 6) - 10px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>

  <div class='right_corner'>
    <div></div>
  </div>

  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>

  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>

  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>

  <div></div>
  <div></div>

</div>
```